# PHP Mailer Attachments Not Uploading?

Tags: php, html, email, attachment, phpmailer

I am trying to set up PHP Mailer to allow me to send attachments, mainly just images, from a form.  I have the following code working except I am not receiving the attachments, they are not being uploaded. Can anybody help me or point me in the right direction as to what I am missing?

PHP

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$current=date('l F dS, Y, H:i a');
$mail->From = 'me@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('karina@live.co.uk', 'Karina McG');
$mail->addAddress('me@live.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('noreply@tempur.com');
$mail->addCC('');
$mail->addBCC('');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');
$mail->isHTML(true);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$system=$_POST['system'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$description=$_POST['description'];

$mail->Subject = "TEMPUR Web Support Request - $system";
$mail->Body = "Dear $name,<br>
<br>
We have received your TEMPUR request form! - $current<br>
<br>
We will be in contact shortly regarding your issue/s.<br>
<br>
Name : $name <br>
Country : $country <br>
Subject : $subject <br>
System : $system <br>
Description : $description"; 

$mail->AltBody = 'Hehehe';

//$to="$email";//Will change to Digital Users email!

   //Send email
if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

?>
```

HTML

```
Upload File:<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload"><br>
```

Comment: Are those files which you are trying to attach actually in those directories relative to your script location? `if(file_exists('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz')){die('woot!');}else{die('nope!');}`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: the paths are absolute, so there's no relativeness at all. question is more whether the files exist.

Comment: I think you are right @MarcB, I really should make myself more familiar with the Linux environment.

Comment: You are right the files don't exist, i get the 'nope' output to screen

Answer (score 0):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form as attribute if it is not their.

also try `$mail->addAttachment($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);`

It will work.